# Why won't my villagers restock their trades?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to trade with 2 of my farmers but they have not restocked their trades in 4 days, they have access to their needs, the tool smith I've been trading with has restocked their trade as well, so I'm confused.

The 2 villagers that won't trade have been zombified and cured once each.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure their actual workstation is reachable?

Comment: they are all able to reach there workstations and i have tested to see them each using them individually yet the trades still dont restock, for now ive just put it down to a bug and left them there as it was only a starter base, ill return to them after a while to see if it changes, its also possible im missing something slight in there behaviour since this is my first trading hall since playing bedrock a while ago with its more "broken" villagers

Comment: Which version are you playing?

Comment: yeah they should restock like twice a day or so, even without beds. four days is a bit much. Are you sure they have access to their original workstations? Maybe break all the other composters you have and/or break and replace the ones in the villagers' area

Comment: im playing on 1.19 @pinckerman and i did see in the last hour that apparently this is actually just a bug with cured villagers and there is only a temporary fix which you can do by completing a raid, doesn't last that long though

i have removed all work blocks from my home and the village and replaced all workblocks in the trading hall aswell

Comment: @Esther ^answered in the above message

Comment: it looks like it is a bug, see https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-251670 https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-252439